# How do I open the Supply Drop?

Tags: firewatch

On Day 33 of Firewatch I was asked to retrieve a supply drop from the northern part of the park. I found the supply drop, but it's locked with a 4 digit passcode. How do I open the supply drop? Should I have found the code to open the lock somewhere?

[image: Map of where supply drop is]

[image: The supply drop]

[image: Passcode]

Comment: It's been several years since I've played this game, but didn't Delilah say all the supply caches have the same password?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Delilah may have given me a code at some point but I don't remember it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the wiki](https://firewatch.fandom.com/wiki/Supply_Cache), all supply boxes have the same code: `1234`